# Usage of gulp-sourcemaps with angular (IIFE pattern). Do I understand sourcemaps correctly?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, source-maps

To begin, this would be the first time I attempt to work with exporting source maps through my gulp builds. I am using angular 1.4.x and we have adopted the following pattern ::

```
(function() {
'use strict';

    var thing = (function() { 
        function thingFunc(thingToInject) {...}

        thingFunc.$inject = ['thingToInject'];
        return thingFunc;
    })();

    angular.module('app').controller('thing', thing);
})();
```

When I run my gulp, I use

```
gulp.task ('thingTask', [], function() {
    return gulp.src(thingFiles)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat(things.Out, { newLine: '\n\n' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(things.Dist));
});
```

And the output is as expected...a bunch of files in sequence with 2 line breaks between each and the entire file ends with a long sourceMap blob of commented text.

What I don't understand is how this blob of text does anything for me. Does the IIFE wrapper I include around each file impose some sort of restriction to how the map file works? When I debug in Chrome, there's really nothing gained by having this source map available. No matter where I may force a break, nothing is available to help the developer locate the actual source file where the problem exists.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell sourcemaps where to write. For the sourcemap line try somehting like:

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'));
```

That should put the sourcemap in the same file as your css.

Then make sure you have sourcemaps configured to work in your browser. More about that can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: fair...and I've had the source map written to an external file...but the string it writes is identical to the string it writes into the base of the distributed js file...I have done it both ways and neither really help me get how the sourcemap helps

Comment: You have sourcemaps enabled in chrome? If so, I would try another browser like firefox or something. That way, you can at least figure out whether its an issue with your browser settings or your build setup because other than that funkiness going on in the `concat` part of your script, everything looks like it should work. You could also omit the `[]` since its not doing anything.

Comment: thanks, I'll check that out...a little off the radar at the moment though...will get back to you soon on what I learn there